# how to change a numeric value that is in jQuery by a variable coming from php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need to replace the value 17 for a variable coming from php.php:

```
$(function() {
 $("#test").paginate({
  count    : 17,
  start    : 1,
  display  : 12,
  border   : true
  ...
 });
});
```

I tried this (didn't work):

```
$(function(){
$("#test").paginate({
 count   : $.post("php.php",function(result){ console.log(result['count']) }),
 start   : 1;
 display : 12;
 border  : true
 ...
});
```

php.php

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
json_encode($count);
```

I am trying this way but i don't know if it's the best way to do that. I appreciate any suggest and help.

Comment: @Blake. The same like `.gnm()`

Comment: @gdoron Can you link me to jquery documentation for it? I can't find that at all.

Comment: @Blake. I'm sorry!!! it was a joke, I have no idea what it is... :) but if it's not an error it's a plugin function, it's not a jQuery code function.

Comment: pag() is just a name i gave to the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Ajax function are asynchronous, or in other words, return instantly then call a callback when they complete. You need to set the count inside the callback like so:

```
$(function(){
    $.post("php.php",function(result){ 
        $("#test").pag({
            count : result
        });
    });
});
```

As per our comments, for multiple values you would need something like

```
$(function(){
    $.post("php.php",function(result){ 
        $("#test").pag({
            count : result.count,
            start : result.start,
            display : result.display
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo json_encode(array(
    'count' => $result,
    'start' => 7,
    'display' => 10,
));
```

Comment: whith this i will print my result in the page, isnt it? But what i need is instead of the number expressed it takes the value of the query result and place there like: `count : $count`

Comment: @Andre if you php page returns a number, then it should work correctly.

Comment: I tried that, and didn't work. I don't know if i expressed myself wrong, but its not recognizing as a number.

Comment: I have to keep the structure and changing only the number 17 by the result of the query which is also 17. That's why i put `$.post("php.php",function(result){ console.log(result['count']) })` instead of 17.

Comment: @Andre, you can use `$.post` like that, the function is asynchronous, look it up...

Comment: still not working for me.. i don't know why. I updated the post for u to understand better. Imagine that i have another variable under the `count`. I just need to change the value 17, not my structure. Got me?

Comment: sry didn't understand, u mean i can't do that?

Comment: @Andre, not the way you are tying to.

Comment: Ok i will update the post with the all jquery.. maybe u can give me a suggest

Comment: if i have more values like this in the post, is that possible to use ur code and add more values like: `count : result, start : 1, ...` ?